# Disable screen dragging in DroidGap

Tags: android, cordova

I am currently working with an hybrid HTML5 mobile application using Cordova. My code is working fine with IOS, I had overcame the bounce effect using **UIWebViewBounce** entry as **NO**, but don't know how to do the same for Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was with the device I switched from Galaxy Tablet 10.1 to Galaxy Note 10.1 and my screen found to be fixed as desired. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the onCreate method of the class that extends DroidGap you will need to add the following code:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=
        android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
    this.appView.setOverScrollMode(appView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
}
```

This should prevent the over scroll bounce effect.